# Powershell: Join path issues with copy item

Tags: powershell

I have the following piece of code:

```
$ServerPath = \\test\ps
$fullpath = Join-Path $ServerPath "\stackoverflow"

Copy-Item $fullpath "c:\"
```

It gives me this output:

```
Cannot find path \test\ps\stackoverflow because it doesn't exist.
```

Inital `\` character is omitted in full path when used with `Copy-Item` command. but `Write-Output` prints value correctly.`

I want to join the path, someone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a little confused - are you sure that \test\ps\stackoverflow actually does exist?  Remember that using \ will point to the root of whatever is the root of your current path (get-location).  So if you're looking at x:\some\sub\folder, \ will point to x:, \test will point to x:\test, and so on.

Comment: Is **test** the host name? If so use: **$ServerPath = "\\test\ps"**

Comment: To add to what Greg said, if you run the code you have, I get an error on the first line because `\\test\ps` is treated as a path to an executable.

Comment: All 3 of you provided pieces of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use quotes when assigning a variable so that PowerShell does not try to execute the command

```
$ServerPath = '\\test\ps'
$fullpath = Join-Path $ServerPath '\stackoverflow'

Copy-Item $fullpath 'c:\'
```